# How do i remove edit profile in frontend in joomla

Tags: css, joomla

I Want to remove or hide the link "edit profile" in the frontend of joomla (versin2.5.6), when i login in site.
Is it possible to remove it?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you can let us know what template you have installed or attach a screenshoot - Help us help you :)

Comment: Where is the link? Is it in a menu? In a module? In the login module?

Comment: are you referring to the "user menu" ?

Answer (score 1):

go to components/com_users/views/profile/tmp/default.php and remove or comment out:

```
//<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=profile.edit&user_id='.(int) $this->data->id);?>">     <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_Edit_Profile'); ?></a> //
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide or disable are two really different things.

If you just want the button to go away use a layout override that doesn't include it. People will still be able to go to the url though.

If it is the profile plugin you mean, you can set the individual fields to show or hide in the  plugin.

If you want to disable the ability to change password I'm not sure that is possible although you could make the field disappear with an override.

Comment: Hi,
I just find a way to remove the link in the frontend.
But when i log, i always go to this page:
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7656891_67295915_783370
is there a way to redirect the users to go directly to homepage menu?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can think of is to add the following to your CSS:

```
ul.actions{
display:none;
}
```